# How can I use window.location.href to download multiple files?

Tags: javascript, download

I have the following javascript:

```
function downloadFiles(){
  var files = [];
  files.push('mysite.com/file1.txt');
  files.push('mysite.com/file2.txt');
  files.push('mysite.com/file3.txt');

  for(var ii=0; ii<files.length; ii++){
    window.location.href = files[ii];
  }
}
```

The problem is this only downloads the last file in the list because the first two files get overwritten by the last one.  How can I wait for the user's input on each file before moving on to the next file?

Comment: You could add an iframe to the DOM for each file in your list and set the iframe's src to the appropriate file url.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I ended up doing:

```
function downloadFiles(){
  var files = [];
  files.push('file1.txt');
  files.push('file2.txt');
  files.push('file3.txt');

  for(var ii=0; ii<files.length; ii++){
    downloadURL(files[ii]);
  }
}

var count=0;
var downloadURL = function downloadURL(url){
  var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader' + count++;
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
  iframe.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  iframe.src = url;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but it's only good for 1-10 files. If you do this for 20 files - chrome will download only 10. FF and IE will skip a lot and pop up a bazillion "where to download?" dialogs. So zipping is the way to go if you have many files you want to give the browser.

Comment: @ubershmekel I didn't realize chrome only downloaded the first 10.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 8):

If you change your code to use `window.open()` instead of `window.location`, you can launch all three downloads at the same time.

I know this doesn't satisfy the requirement of waiting on the user's input before presenting each of the downloads, but it does build off of the spirit of your original code. Hopefully it will help a little.

```
function downloadFiles(){
  var files = [];
  files.push('file1.txt');
  files.push('file2.txt');
  files.push('file3.txt');

  for(var ii=0; ii<files.length; ii++){
    window.open(files[ii]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

old one but the solution for this that I ended up going with is the following

```
let currentIndex = 0;
const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  if (currentIndex === files.length - 1) clearInterval(intervalId);
  window.location.href = files[currentIndex];
  currentIndex++;
}, 1000);
```