# Trying to download a file with javascript works in some browsers but not others

Tags: javascript, html, function, browser, download

I have a problem I can’t solve.  The following function inputs a file path and name and downloads the file.  It works for chrome and edge browsers but with Vivaldi and pale moon browsers it will work once but not a second time.  You need to reload the browser for it to work again.  I have isolated the problem to this function alone.  The alert works for all browsers, (first and second times) and shows the appropriate file path and name but no download takes place after the first successful attempt.  There is no error in console.  I thought that perhaps the browser didn’t like the creation of ‘var a’ a second time so included the ‘a.remove()’ but it makes no difference.

```
function StartDownload(filePath, fileName) {    // this is the function to download the book. Creates an html object 'a', adds the url to it, and then downloads it  
  //alert("got here: " + filePath + " fileName is: " + fileName);

  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = fileUrl;
  a.setAttribute("download", fileName);
  a.click();

  //a.remove();
}
```

Could anyone suggest possible reasons why this code won’t download in those browsers after the first time?

Comment: Have you tried just setting the windows href to the download page instead of creating an anchor link and clicking it? Like this: `window.location = filePath;` ? Also, what is the variable `fileUrl` doing in your code? Where does it come from?

Comment: It should be `a.href = filePath` not fileUrl

Comment: Also, in javascript it doesn't really matter if you use `var`, `let` or `const` to declare a variable inside a function. They will all be function scoped and none of them will be reassigned the next time you call the function.

Comment: sorry, I changed the code before posting to try to make it clearer.  fileUrl is actually filePath and I didn't see the second reference. (and actually made it less clearer! gulp!)

Comment: I'm trying to understand Laisender's comment.  If I make window.location = filePath, and don't create an anchor link and click it, then how will I actually stimulate the download?

Comment: found a way to follow Laisender - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453595/how-can-i-use-window-location-href-to-download-multiple-files